# Show row from block of string without cursors or while loops

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a variable containig numerous of lines with string looking like that:

`senteqweqence some text
sentence -1 some text
sendasdadadastence other text`

My goal is to extract the first line from this variable cointaining the string `-1` regardless of the  text above or below the line, without using cursors or while loops.

Expected result: `sentence -1 some text`

What i have tried so far:

```
DECLARE 
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @end int,
    @start int

SET @sql = 
'senteqweqence some text
sentence -1 some text
sendasdadadastence other text'

SET @end = CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),@sql,CHARINDEX('-1',@sql))

SET @start = CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),REVERSE(@sql),1)

PRINT SUBSTRING(@sql,@start,@end-@start)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should get you going. You might need to add or subtract a character at either end of the substring:

```
SET @end = CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),@sql,CHARINDEX('-1',@sql))  
SET @start = @end - CHARINDEX(CHAR(10),REVERSE(LEFT(@sql,@end)),CHARINDEX('1-',REVERSE(LEFT(@sql,@end))))+2
PRINT SUBSTRING(@sql,@start,@end-@start)
```

Comment: What is the output if you do a `SELECT @start, @end` instead of PRINT?

Comment: I've edited my answer. In the `@start` calculation you need to change '-1' to '1-' since you are searching in a reverse string :-) Now it works according to this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16291/1/0).

Comment: After some testing i found out that if my variable contains `-1` twice it breaks.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It should now account for multiple occurences of -1 by only returning the first row that contains a -1.